# Cascading dropdownlist for telerik asp.net mvc extensions

Tags: telerik-mvc

I want to be able to have let's say two dropdownlists where the data retrieved from the second dropdownlist depends on the selectedvalue of the first dropdownlist.

I know I would execute an html.beginform executing a specific action method in a controller for the first, but I can't figure out a way to do it based on that value for the second..

I also need a way to get the selectedindex of the item that was checked.

Can someone help me out and inform me how I can accomplish this please?

A code snippet would be greatly appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the cascading functionality? Everything you need to know and configure is covered in this [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox/cascadingcombobox) here.